# Solving Linear Equations in Level-1 S-Function Versus Matlab Coder

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I have a matlab level-1 s-function that I use to solve a system of linear equations. Unfortunately, my simulations are very slow, and the Profiler Report tells me that this particular s-function is the time hog. Since I have access to Matlab Coder, I have the chance of converting my s-function to C++ code. However, it isn't so straightforward because the signals to the matlab sfunction are variable size, and it would require some effort to achieve the same thing in C++ (although I know it can be done).

Before I undertake it, I would like to ask, is it generally true that all CMEX code runs faster than level-1 s-function? Especially code generated using `codegen`? More importantly, does the backslash operator work at the same speed in CMEX?

Comment: The backslash operator won't work at all in c -- it's purely an m-code syntax.  You'd most likely be better (if possible) to convert your code to use a MATLAB Function block (which does support converting mldivide, i.e. backslash, to c-code).

Comment: Hi @PhilGoddard, yes that was my plan. Typically, I write an s-function in matlab level-1, because then it is easy to debug. After that, I get rid of the s-function part of it, and just copy everything into a typical matlab .m function. Then I use Matlab Coder and let it do the conversion for me. Finally, I write a wrapper code for it and compile everything to a CMEX using the `mex` function. That is my plan for this, with the caveat that I need to incorporate variable size signals.

Comment: Why not write it within a MATLAB Function Block, which is slightly different to a standard m-code function, and eliminate the need to use MATLAB Coder?

Comment: In my experience, that slows down our simulations even further, due to the fact that we have some internal libraries that _also_ need to be called from within the s-function. We end up having to use `coder.extrinsic` a lot, and the results just aren't as fast.